# Geocoding with county level .Locator Style

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geocoding

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 locators to geocode some addresses on a state by state level,
using the dual ranges locator style.

Since I have the administration levels city/county/state on both datasets (reference data and addresses to geocode), I would like to add them when creating the locator so that it geolocates on groups: city/county/state. The issue I'm finding is that on locator creation of Dual Ranges style, I can't find a way to add the county level, I only see the city left and right, and state left and right along with other reference attributes.

Comment: Counties are typically not considered part of addresses. While a city *can* fall in two counties, the city part is the one that would be more specific. Only specialized data for emergency services response would be likely to have locator attributes for the county level, not postal type address data.